How to use intent (custom URIs) in kivy
I'm trying to get a kivy app (built with buildozer) to open a deep link. Basically I would like to send the user a redirect in the web browser, which would "trigger" the kivy app and get it to open (passing some data along with it). After commenting out the following line in buildozer:
# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
android.manifest.intent_filters = intent_filters.xml

and creating the file intent_filters.xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="test_app" android:host="set_intro_text"/>
</intent-filter>

I've tried the following code:
from jnius import autoclass
..
def on_start(self):
    # Register for the intent when app is started
    activity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
    intent = activity.getIntent()
    data = intent.getData()

    # Check if the app was launched with a specific URL scheme
    if data:
        self.user_label.text = f'Hello from outside> {data.getScheme()}'

When I open a web browser (chrome or Samsung Internet) and enter the url:
test_app://set_intro_text?data="opened from chrome"

This does not work, the browsers continue to treat it as a query and they redirect to the default search engine. Does anybody have a clue as to why this doesn't work?

For anyone facing the same issue: android has changed the way apps are called from the web browser. The following works (opens the app, sent as a custom redirect from Django):
intent://set_intro_text/#Intent;scheme=test_app;package=org.test.browser_test;S.text_from_outside=hello;end

Make sure to adjust the scheme, package and host for your specific app. In kivy you can get the (extra) text string:
attached_text = intent.getStringExtra('text_from_outside')

